# How to call function and display results after clicking button

Tags: javascript, html, json, amazon-web-services

So the function test() lists the items in a dynamoDB table. I'm trying to call the function after a button is clicked. I tested the function out on it's own and it works. I just don't know how to call it after a click and return and display the data. The code is in javascript and some HTML. I'm very new to this so any help is appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Amplify from 'aws-amplify';
import awsconfig from './aws-exports';
import { AmplifySignOut, withAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

function App() {
  return (
  <div className="App">
  <header className="App-header">
  <AmplifySignOut />
  <h2>Room Reservation System</h2>
  </header>
  
  <b>
    A little bit of information is needed:
  </b>


    <form>
      <lable for="meetingdate">Date of meeting: 
        <input type="date" name="meetingdate" required pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}">
        </input>
        <span class="validity"></span>
        </lable>
    </form>

  <p>
    Time of meeting: 
    <select id="selecttime">
      <option value="9am">9 AM</option>
      <option value="10am">10 AM</option>
      <option value="11am">11 AM</option>
      <option value="12pm">12 PM</option>
      <option value="1pm">1 PM</option>
      <option value="2pm">2 PM</option>
      <option value="3pm">3 PM</option>
      <option value="4pm">4 PM</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <p>
    Duration of meeting (Max 3 Hours): 
    <select id="selectduration">
      <option value="1">1 Hour</option>
      <option value="2">2 Hours</option>
      <option value="3">3 Hours</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <p>
    Meeting Capacity (Minimum of 4 People, Max of 10): 
    <select id="selectcap">
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
      <option value="6">6</option>
      <option value="7">7</option>
      <option value="8">8</option>
      <option value="9">9</option>
      <option value="10">10</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <script> {
  function read() {
   var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
   let awsConfig = {
    "region": "us-west-2",
    "endpoint": "http://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "accessKeyId": "AKIATXDQF3UYRZV****", "secretAccessKey": "4azvTl67U8QW1id0j8Ck3/rAOqmEp4ajnKF*****"
};
AWS.config.update(awsConfig);
console.log('test');
let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
 
dynamoDB
    .scan({
        TableName: "Rooms",
    })
    .promise()
    .then(data => console.log(data.Items))
    .catch(console.error)
 }
}
 </script>
  <button type="button" onclick="read()">FIND ROOM</button>

</div>
 );
 }


export default withAuthenticator (App);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSX button should look like:

```
<button type="button" onClick={read}>FIND ROOM</button>
```

I would also remove the script tags and place the read() function above the return in your App component. This would be your code:

```
import React from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from "./aws-exports";
import { AmplifySignOut, withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

function App() {
  
  const read = () => {
    var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    let awsConfig = {
      region: "us-west-2",
      endpoint: "http://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
      accessKeyId: "AKIATXDQF3UYRZV****",
      secretAccessKey: "4azvTl67U8QW1id0j8Ck3/rAOqmEp4ajnKF*****",
    };
    AWS.config.update(awsConfig);
    console.log("test");
    let docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    const dynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    dynamoDB
      .scan({
        TableName: "Rooms",
      })
      .promise()
      .then((data) => console.log(data.Items))
      .catch(console.error);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <AmplifySignOut />
        <h2>Room Reservation System</h2>
      </header>

      <b>A little bit of information is needed:</b>

      <form>
        <lable for="meetingdate">
          Date of meeting:
          <input type="date" name="meetingdate" required pattern="\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"></input>
          <span class="validity"></span>
        </lable>
      </form>

      <p>
        Time of meeting:
        <select id="selecttime">
          <option value="9am">9 AM</option>
          <option value="10am">10 AM</option>
          <option value="11am">11 AM</option>
          <option value="12pm">12 PM</option>
          <option value="1pm">1 PM</option>
          <option value="2pm">2 PM</option>
          <option value="3pm">3 PM</option>
          <option value="4pm">4 PM</option>
        </select>
      </p>

      <p>
        Duration of meeting (Max 3 Hours):
        <select id="selectduration">
          <option value="1">1 Hour</option>
          <option value="2">2 Hours</option>
          <option value="3">3 Hours</option>
        </select>
      </p>

      <p>
        Meeting Capacity (Minimum of 4 People, Max of 10):
        <select id="selectcap">
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
          <option value="9">9</option>
          <option value="10">10</option>
        </select>
      </p>

      <button type="button" onClick={read}>
        FIND ROOM
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

Comment: I tried that but now the code won't compile. "'read' is not defined  no-undef"

Comment: Where would you add that last piece of code in my script?

Comment: The code compiles now, but the button still doesn't do anything:

Comment: @jordanlong1 Try now. I forgot to change 'onclick' to onClick' on the button. In React, JSX attributes are formatted in camelCase, unlike the lower case format for HTML.

Comment: It's still not doing anything. Do you you think its because I need a place to display it?